# How to display headers on multiple pages using syncfusion

Tags: c#, syncfusion

I have a table report which will be exported as a word document. I can print out the header in the first page only. It doesn't seem to carry over to the next page. Can anyone tell me how I can show the header data on all the pages of the word document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was a lot easier than I expected. All I had to do was put the header data I wanted in the header of the **Word Ddocument Template** that I wanted to use. Also in order to have the header of a table to apear repeatedly when there are multiple pages, again we go to the **Word Document Template**, select the rows you want to use as headers then right click and go to Properties -> Rows tab -> enable(check) "Reapeat as header row at the top of each page" -> click OK and save. That should do the trick!! Then use syncfusion as you usually use it to populate the table. When the data exceed to more than one page the header will be repeated on the following pages.